# Is there any error in .htaccess rewriting rules

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to make search engine friendly urls for my website using .htaccess in Apache

I want to redirect url `http://localhost/simple_blog/tmp` to

`http://localhost/simple_blog/tmp.php`

here are my rewriting rules

```
 RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
 RewriteRule ^tmp/?$  tmp.php [NC,L]
```

It works fine when i use

`http://localhost/simple_blog/tmp/`

or

`http://localhost/simple_blog/tmp`

But when i use

`http://localhost/simple_blog/tmp.`

why it redirect to

`http://localhost/simple_blog/tmp.php`

I expected it should throw 404 because according to regex it should match `'tmp'` at beginning and '/' is optional and then end of string

Is there any error in regex ??

Comment: I switched to ubuntu 12.04 now working as expected

Answer (score 1):

`^` asserts the position at the beginning of the string, which is `http://...`

The `?` quantifier **does** make the `/` optional.

So I think the correct regex would be `tmp/?$` for your purposes... Technically that should work. I'm not sure how PHP handles regex though.

You could also try a negative lookahead such as `tmp/?(?!\.+)$` on the end of your regex

Comment: `http://localhost/simple_blog/tmp.?` this too redirect to
`http://localhost/simple_blog/tmp.php`.


Do you have any idea what's going on ??

Comment: That string is not matched by the regex provided. Is that matching in your code? It would be very strange if it is.

Comment: I double checked if i put in browser `http://localhost/simple_blog/tmp.?`
it's opening `http://localhost/simple_blog/tmp.php`

Comment: It could be that `tmp.` is resolving to `tmp` before submitting to the browser? or the server could be dropping the `.` for some reason

Comment: You could try a negative lookahead such as `tmp/?(?!\.+)$` on the end of your regex